# INSERT array into mysql table (only zeros as result)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hello I have an array ($ar) like the following.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 44409
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 44428
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 44313
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 42296
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 44429
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 42979
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 42302
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 42301
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [ciao] => 43011
 )

    [10] => 
)
```

I am trying to insert the array into a mysql table but I only get zeros everywhere with the following code.

```
"mysql connection"
$i = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
$sql = " INSERT INTO table(yo) VALUES('".$ar[$i]."') " ;
echo $ar[$i];

    $req = mysql_query($sql) ;  
}
mysql_close($db1);
```

Could anyone help? If I try to echo the `$r[$i]` it displays the string "array" instead of the proper numbers in the actual array.

Comment: Where are you getting `$r` from? Isn't the array called `$ar`?

Comment: yes it is $ar, just modified, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside each item in your array $ar there is another array.

So your query should be:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO table(yo) VALUES('".$ar[$i]['ciao']."') " ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(yo) VALUES('{$ar[$i]['ciao']}') " ;
```